# Golang workspace for a project

Tags: go

I have a golang project and I put the code somewhere in git server.
All my code are now on $GOPATH/mygitserver/folder/.

Everything is goods until the time that the gitserver is changes the url, so I need to replace all import to new gitserver url. So, i don't want to have it again in the future and want to change the way it works.

So instead of push the package only to my git server, now I am planning to upload the entire workspace to git (exclude the external library). So, I will have a package direcly to src folder (example : src/mypackage). So, when I change the gitserver url, everything will still works.

The question is : is it a good practice to do it (upload the workspace to git)? Or do we have another option?

And also it comes with another problem that not exist before. So, after I clone my workspace, I have to call "go get" for all of my library used by the project. (This not happen before because when I call go get mygitserver/package, Golang automatically download the dependency). Is there any way to make all the dependency downloaded my just one command?

Answer (score 3):

If you expect your server to move frequently one possible solution is to use a [vanity import path](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

Vanity import paths allow you to keep your code at an import path on a domain you own which redirects you to the location where the code is stored. For instance, if you host your code on Bitbucket but are worried you might move in the future and you own the domain `example.net`, you could host your code such that you'd import it with `import "example.net/myproject"` and behind the scenes the `go get` tool would fetch it from Bitbucket. To do this, you must serve a document on the domain you want that contains a custom meta tag of the form:

```
<meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">
```

So for instance serving the following HTML file at `example.net/myproject` would redirect `go get` to clone the provided Bitbucket URL (it could also of course point to any other Git service including your own):

```
<meta name="go-import" content="example.net/myproject git https://bitbucket.org/myname/myproject.git">
```

To configure Nginx to serve these redirects, a configuration like the following can be used (replacing `myPackage` and the URLs with your projects name and URLs, of course):

```
location ~ /myPackage/[a-z][a-z0-9]* {
    if ($args = "go-get=1") {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 '<meta name="go-import" content="$host/myPackage git https://bitbucket.org/myName/myPackage.git">';
    }
    rewrite ^ https://mygithosting.example.org/myName/myPackage? permanent;
}
location ~ /myPackage$ {
    if ($args = "go-get=1") {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
        return 200 '<meta name="go-import" content="$host/myPackage git https://mygithosting.example.org/myName/myPackage.git">';
    }
    rewrite ^ https://mygithosting.example.org/myName/myPackage? permanent;
}
```

Now any time you move your Git server, you can just change the URL in the meta tag.

If you're worried about some users importing directly from your Git server and others using the vanity import path, you can also set this path as the packages canonical import path. Canonical import paths are specified as special comments on the `package` line in one file of a Go program (it doesn't matter which one). They look like this:

```
import mypackage // import "example.com/mypackage"
```

Now if the above code is actually hosted somewhere else and someone tries to import it directly, `go get` will complain:

$ go get mygithosting.example.org/myName/myPackage
package mygithosting.example.org/myName/myPackage: code in directory /go/mygithosting.example.org/myName/myPackage expects import "example.com/mypackage"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you think by upload the entire workspace is a good?

Comment: Oops, sorry, yah, I could have addressed the original question at the begining. I don't know your particular use case well enough to say, but in general I'd say "no, that's a bad idea". It's just going to make things harder to manage as your workspace grows, and people will have to create work arounds and hacks to make it fit in with their normal development process (where they may want things in their workspace that aren't in the global one, but that they don't want to accidentally check in to Git).